# Who should our moderators be?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation

> If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice. [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)

- **Each nomination should be a separate answer**. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

We're looking for members of this site who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

It's also good if the moderators:

- Are members with participation in both the meta and main site.
- Participated in Area 51, generate social network referrals, or blog about the site.
- Are members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

---

<sub>Shamelessly copied from [meta.puzzling](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/171/39), which was in turn copied from meta.space. ;)</sub>

Answer (score 15):

I am interested in being a moderator -- at least, I would be willing to do so at this early stage until better moderators appear. I'm active and interested in building this site as a better place than SO for a growing body of data-science-related questions.

Pros:

- Top 1% SO user, and active in data-science-related tags: https://stackoverflow.com/users/64174/sean-owen
- A top-4 active user here so far: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all and https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/21/sean-owen
- I visit StackExchange daily and enjoy reading, answering, and contributing to improvement through voting/flags
- On a related note, a top writer on Quora, and in data science topics, arguably a similar type of community: https://www.quora.com/Sean-Owen

Cons:

- I have not been an SO moderator before
- I have not been active much on this meta site yet (https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21/sean-owen)

Comment: It would be great if we could see some participation on meta.

Answer (score 4):

I nominate AsheeshR ([datascience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/62/asheeshr) profile; [meta.datascience](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/users/62/asheeshr) profile).

Asheesh is among the most active users during the beta so far. He has participated in [many other sites in the network](http://stackexchange.com/users/1609527/asheeshr?tab=accounts) and shows a [nuanced understanding of the beta process](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/43/322). He has engaged in [community building](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9/322) activities and has [prior experience as a moderator pro tem](https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/147). Apart from that, I think the quality of his contributions, in terms of questions, answers, and comments, speaks for itself.

Answer (score 3):

I'm interested in becoming a moderator on this site.

I enjoy checking this site a few times a day and participating in discussions. Frequently, I find myself flagging posts, editing questions, and upvoting answers. I also kindly re-direct people to other SE sites when appropriate, or help people re-phrase their questions to be more appropriate here.

As a web engineer, I have a lot of experience with web site features. I can see shortcomings in functionality, and have posted a few suggestions on the meta site.

Contributing to this community in a more direct way would be fun for me. I'm already doing a bit of leg-work, suggesting that moderators look at content and asking users to improve their posts. I think it would save the moderators time to just have me take care of these kinds of problems, rather than have them take a look as well.